# jQuery AJAX Geolocation Not Working

Tags: jquery, ajax, geolocation

I am using freegeoip's API to get the location of the visitor. I have tried putting the code in `$(document).ready` (without click event) and also in `click` event but in both cases, it seems as though the AJAX call doesn't run. I've got the code from [Shopify's webpage](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/store-wide/get-a-visitors-location#free-web-service) but since it's just jQuery, it should work in any cases with jQuery.

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzkft370/)

Here's the JavaScript code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('button').click(function(){
        jQuery.ajax( { 
          url: 'http://freegeoip.net/json/', 
          type: 'POST', 
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          success: function(location) {
            jQuery('#location').append(location.country_code);
          }
        } );
    });
});
```

Here's the simple HTML :

```
<button type="button">Button</button>
<div id="location"></div>
```

Does anyone have any idea what went wrong? I've spent hours checking it but couldn't spot any obvious problems. I've also tried using another API and `$.getJSON` but could never get it work. There was also no error message in the console. I just wish to run it after page load and upon success, execute some other functions.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Fiddle works for me.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I've tested it on another computer and it seems to work there, but not on this computer which I'm using (both using same internet connection through LAN). Any ideas why? I've tested it on both Firefox and Chrome on this computer but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is finally identified. It's AdBlockPlus which has blocked freegeoip.net, that's why it doesn't work on this computer only (and I have that plugin installed for all my browsers).

Hope this helps for anyone facing similar issues.